# Login con campos de la base de datos

Tags: c#, login

¿Cómo pudiera hacer un login, que me solicite el nombre del servidor, de la base de datos, el usuario de la base de datos y la contraseña de la misma en C#?

```
SqlConnection conexion =
new SqlConnection("server='" txt_server.text; database='" +
nom_db + "' ;  user='" + user_db + "' ; password='" +
pass_db + "'");
```

Algo así, pero si es posible usando clases que me permitan ingresar estos parametros.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias.
[image: Así seria el formulario.]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es hacer una cadena de conexión. Para ello, dependiendo del tipo de base de datos a la que vayamos a conectarnos tenemos varias opciones, por ejemplo:

Para **Microsoft SQLServer** tenemos **SqlConnectionStringBuilder** que viene incluida en el paquete *System.Data.SqlClient* y que se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

//Creamos la cadena de conexión
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlConnectionBuilder.DataSource = "SERVIDOR";
sqlConnectionBuilder.UserID = "USUARIO";
sqlConnectionBuilder.Password = "CONTRASEÑA";
sqlConnectionBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;

//Cargamos la cadena de conexión al SqlConnection
sqlConnection.ConnectionString = sqlConnectionBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Para **MySQL** podemos usar la clase **MySqlConnectionStringBuilder** que viene importada junto con el controlador en el paquete *MySql.Data.MySqlClient* y se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder.Server = "SERVIDOR";
connectionStringBuilder.Port = "PUERTO";
connectionStringBuilder.UserID = "USUARIO";
connectionStringBuilder.Password = "CONTRASEÑA";
connectionStringBuilder.Database = "BASE DE DATOS";
connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionTimeout = 30;

//Obtenemos la cadena de conexión
string connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString()
```

Comment: Hola **@Trewqa**, pero ¿como haría para que realice la validación?. Ejemplo: si el usuario no es correcto , o quizás el password, etc. Me puedes ayudar con eso.  Gracias.